# IE7 text-align not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, text-align

I have a simple horizontal UL LI main nav which I am trying to align to the center of the page. Text-align, which works in the other browsers is working but this does not work in IE7.

Is there something I am missing about this bug in IE7?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show html/css code?

Comment: Hi Fantactuka. I'm still working on localhost but seem to have found a solution for now which I will answer now. Thanks!

Comment: `width: auto;` should help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its bug is IE7 :

so look this post where in artile he discuss about the bug and solution for this bug : http://haslayout.net/css/Text-Align-Bug

Also check this post  : http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943560/html-alignment-issue-in-one-machine-only-both-ie8 ?

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Seems if I add a conditional CSS for IE7 and say:

```
.RadNav .RadMenu ul.rmRootGroup {
display:inline;}
```

Rather than:

```
.RadNav .RadMenu ul.rmRootGroup {
display:inline-block;}
```

It works.

I would appreciate some thoughts on this as I would love to not be able to use conditional css.

Thanks!